# Bottom of text getting clipped for NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I'm experiencing issues displaying an `NSAttributedString` properly through a `UILabel`, causing the bottom of the text to be clipped. In one version, I made the frame of the `UILabel`'s background color red, and it looks like it is an issue with the way the text is being drawn rather than the frame.[image]

Comment: In the label with the red background, the top padding looks larger than the bottom padding. What happens when you increase the label frame?

Comment: That worked, didn't realize that the label adds padding!

Comment: Re: the labels (which shouldn't inherently pad) — you haven't accidentally set a `contentInset` or anything like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the label with the red background, the top padding looks larger than the bottom padding. What happens when you increase the label frame?